# What function does the context menu item "View Code" do in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project of pure C++. I don't know what function the context menu item *View Code* really does, so I want to remove it permanently.

The steps:

1. *Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Context menu -> Editor Context Menus | Code Window;*
2. *Choose "<> View Code" and click "Delete";*
3. *Restart VS, and "<> View Code" **still appears** in the context menu when right-clicking on the code editor as shown in the picture.*

My questions:

1. **What function does the menu item *View Code* do?**
2. **How to remove the menu item from the context menu permanently?**

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the button normally used to show the code when you are on a WinForms/WPF GUI editor ?

Comment: My project is of pure C++ and the current file in the editor is a cpp file, so "View Code" shouldn't appear here.

Comment: Totally agree with you here. I have just tested with a blank WinForms project. If I'm on the GUI editor it opens the code of the WinForms, but if I click on it when in the code, it does nothing. However I have tried to do what you did to remove it and the change was permanent, even after a restart. I use Community 2019 16.3.5.

Comment: My version is 16.5

Comment: I have updated to 16.5.4 and the bug does not seem to reproduce. I have found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/972722/new-find-in-files-options-are-not-saved.html) in the changelog for 16.5.4, maybe it is linked ?